# How to create a virtual Android device for Qt Creator?

Tags: android, qt, sdk, qt-creator

I have Qt Creator and Qt 5.8 on Windows 7 x64.

I have installed:

- Android Studio
- `jdk-8u121-windows-x64`
- `qt-opensource-windows-x86-android-5.8.0`
- downloaded and extracted `apache-ant-1.10.1-bin`.

Then I followed the [Creating a Mobile Application](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/qtcreator-accelbubble-example.html) document and created a project named `Andapp1`:

[image: Project Folder Contents]
[image: Project Tree]

There were some errors indicated in General Messages, but I don't know if they were relevant:

[image: General messages]

Then I was recommended to follow the [Connecting Android Devices](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-developing-android.html) document. Thus I set the *Android tab* as follows:

[image: Android Options]

Finally, I tried to run my *Andapp1* project in Qt Creator, but it needed an Android virtual device:

[image: No Device Found Dialog]

Then I was suggested to follow [Using the Android Emulator](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-developing-android.html#using-the-android-emulator) document, but it's not clear how to!

Below is my *Android SDK Manager*'s state:

[image: Android SDK Manager Screenshot]

I can't figure out how should I interpret the documentation to create and connect an *Android virtual device* to the Qt Creator to be able to run the *Andapp1* Android app!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Kuba Ober: Thank you very much for your edition.

Comment: Isn't there any answer for my question?! :-(

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect a real android device to your pc or create an android virtual device before running your program.
Click "Android Virtual Device" button on this window:
[See This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCZEN.png)